# How to make a Promise.all with several request

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, request-promise

I am trying to go through the list I have of cars to generate the `request`. These generated requests I want to store in a list but without executing them even to pass it later to an `axios.all` but the error I get is that at the time of storing the requests in the list they are executed.

[axios module](https://github.com/axios/axios)

```
const axios = require("axios")

let requests = []
cars.forEach(car => requests.push(requestUpdateStatus(car)))

axios.all(requests).then(result => console.log(result)).catch(error => console.log(error))


function requestUpdateStatus(car) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let jsonResponse = JSON.stringify({
            model: car.model,
            year: car.year
        })

        axios.post('http://???/update-status', jsonResponse, { timeout: 50000 })
            .then(response => {
                resolve("HELLO")
            }).catch(error => {
                reject("*** ERROR ***")
            })
    })

}
```

Comment: Just a note about style and code cleanliness: you can drastically clean up the requests array creation code by doing this: `let requests = cars.map(requestUpdateStatus)`

Comment: This question needs to be closed: the OP changed the question after two answers were posted, invalidating both answers. At this point, it’s not clear what the real code looks like. A [mre] is missing. Unfortunately, OP’s account is deleted, so there’s nothing that can be done here.

Answer (score 3):

You need to *return* the `Promise`:

```
function requestUpdateStatus(car) {
    let jsonResponse = JSON.stringify({
        model: car.model,
        year: car.year
    })

    return axios.post('http://???/update-status', jsonResponse, { timeout: 3000 })
        .then(response => {
            console.log("HELLO")
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log("*** ERROR ***")
        })
}
```

Otherwise, it looks good.

Answer (score 0):

You're not returning the promise from requestUpdateStatus, so there's nothing being pushed into the requests array to resolve.